# Docker postgres does not run init file in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Based on Docker's Postgres [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/), I can create any `*.sql` file inside `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` and have it automatically run.

I have `init.sql` that contains `CREATE DATABASE ronda;`

In my `docker-compose.yaml`, I have

```
web:
  restart: always
  build: ./web
  expose:
    - "8000"
  links:
    - postgres:postgres
  volumes:
    - /usr/src/app/static
  env_file: .env
  command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn ronda.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000

nginx:
  restart: always
  build: ./nginx/
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - /www/static
  volumes_from:
    - web
  links:
    - web:web

postgres:
  restart: always
  build: ./postgres/
  volumes_from:
    - data
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"

data:
  restart: always
  build: ./postgres/
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/postgresql
  command: "true"
```

and my postgres Dockerfile,

```
FROM library/postgres

RUN mkdir -p /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Running `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up` work fine, but the database `ronda` is not created.

Comment: Do you see https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/d1644850949964935c418a73e0a7dc36f4f12dd9/docker-entrypoint.sh#L80?

Comment: That's weird, I don't see that.

Comment: So it isn't executed, or exits before that line is reached.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem with postgres 11.

Some points that helped me:

- run:

  - **`docker-compose rm`**
  - `docker-compose build`
  - `docker-compose up`
- The obvious: don't run compose in detached mode. You want to see the logs.

After adding the step `docker-compose rm` to the mix it worked, finally.

Answer (score 3):

If your initialisation requirements are just to create the `ronda` schema, then you could just make use of the `POSTGRES_DB` environment variable as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/postgres/README.md#postgres_db).

The bit of your *docker-compose.yml* file for the postgres service would then be:

```
postgres:
  restart: always
  build: ./postgres/
  volumes_from:
    - data
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  environment:
    POSTGRES_DB: ronda
```

---

On a side note, do not use `restart: always` for your `data` container as this container does not run any service (just the `true` command). Doing this you are basically telling Docker to run the `true` command in an infinite loop.

Comment: I haven't had any POSTGRES_DB specified, default db is named postgres so use that

Answer (score 3):

This is how I use **postgres** on my projects and preload the database.

**file:** docker-compose.yml

```
  db:
    container_name: db_service
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

This `Dockerfile` load the file named `pg_dump.backup`(binary dump) or `psql_dump.sql`(plain text dump) if exist on root folder of the project.

**file:** Dockerfile.postgres

```
FROM postgres:9.6-alpine

ENV POSTGRES_DB DatabaseName

COPY pg_dump.backup .
COPY pg_dump.sql .

RUN [[ -e "pg_dump.backup" ]] && pg_restore pg_dump.backup > pg_dump.sql

# Preload database on init
RUN [[ -e "pg_dump.sql" ]] && cp pg_dump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

In case of need retry the loading of the dump, you can remove the current database with the command:

```
docker-compose rm db
```

Then you can run `docker-compose up` to retry load the database.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing was worked for me after couples of hours i solved it.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:slim
WORKDIR /app
RUN mkdir -p /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/  -> Add this line
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ ./
EXPOSE 4000
CMD node index.js
```

docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: 'user'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'pass'
      POSTGRES_DB: 'db'
    volumes:
      - ./scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d -> this should be present

  server:
    build:
      context: .
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - '4000:4000'
```

Make a folder named scripts add all scripts in it and give path of that directory in volume

```
volumes:
   - {dirpath (relative to Dockerfile)}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

It worked for me.