# Docker-Compose Postgresql import dump

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a question about docker and postgres. I am setting up a new postgres database every time docker is starting up and want to import a given dump.

My Problem is like, but the answers are not sufficient for me: [Docker postgres does not run init file in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691412/docker-postgres-does-not-run-init-file-in-docker-entrypoint-initdb-d)

Docker-Compose:

```
postgres:
  environment:
   - POSTGRES_USER=****
   - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=****
   - POSTGRES_DB=****
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: dockerfile-postgres
```

My Dockerfile: (I tried it already with a script with .sh ending)

```
FROM postgres
ADD dump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

According to https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/ dump.sql must be used to import the database.

Starting up the application with docker only gives:

```
postgres_1     | LOG:  invalid record length at 0/1708600
postgres_1     | LOG:  redo is not required
postgres_1     | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
postgres_1     | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres_1     | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

Besides I tested if my database has been imported, there is no table in my database. What am I doing wrong (files are read- and executable on target system)? Importing it with psql is no problem, so my dump is correct.

I hope you can help me and I want to thank you in advance for it.

Comment: Hope to remeber it right, but `ADD` only runs magic, when being a URL as in [Docker COPY vs ADD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958140/docker-copy-vs-add) discussed. Would you not want to run `pr_restore` and give this the path to your `dump.sql` copy? ... but maybe `pg_restore` does not work with containerized variant (as the comment - 18 days old - on the postgres docker hub page suggests)

Comment: Yeah i thought about Copy to and tried it, same result. The file is correctly in target. I already tried with a pqdump and an sh script in this folder. The script should have only called: pg_restore -d databasename /tmp/dump.backup. The pg_restore itself worked on target machine, but the script is not being executed

Comment: It is pg_restore what you want I guess - not dump what is in the DB but fill back in, right?

Comment: The sql file or importing the dump is not the problem, my script imported it correctly, if executed manually. My problem is docker won't execute it

Comment: Sorry, to suggest the following, but ...did you try to name it `init.sql`instead of `dump.sql` already ...? That might be the level of magic, that could lead to exec in such a magic folder.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Okay I found the trick, I have to execute "docker-compose rm" in order to execute the scripts and sql files within this folder. Once built and not removed the init folder is being ignored.

**UPDATE**
I ran into this problem again, this time removing the images docker created resolved the problem.

Comment: Just a note that you may also need to do `docker-compose build` after you run `docker-compose rm` if you've altered the `ADD`ed scripts.

Comment: life saver... even doing a clean of all docker images and layers did not work, but this did.

Comment: as this seems to be a common problem or research, it would be much appreciated if this answer goes a bit more in details

Answer (score -1):

It is happening because most probably

The initdb scripts `docker-entryfile.sh` which is then responsible for running `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*` files in alphabetical order runs for the first time only when the volumes are being created.

You can see some details [here](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/40) .

Solution ( works with me ) 
This is snippet from my docker-compose file

```
  postgres_service:
    build:
      context : docker-postgres
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-base
    image: 'datahub/postgres:development'
    user: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - credentials/postgres/development.env
    volumes:
      - /Users/yogesh.yadav/DockerData/datahub/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - datahubnetwork
```

Steps -

1) `docker-compose -f docker-compose-filename.yml down`

or

`docker-compose -f docker-compose-filename.yml stop postgres_service`

2) Remove the volume/volumes ( /Users/yogesh.yadav/DockerData/datahub/postgresql/data ) attached with postgres_service docker service. You can do this manually or via `docker-compose rm` or `docker volume rm`.  Please identify your volume which are attached to that postgres service before removing it. [More info here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#remove-volumes)

3) Docker uses very good cache management via building images and running them. If you did not modify your `Dockerfile` , docker is going to run the already build image from the cache and run it. So I would advise to remove the images for postgres_service as well.

To List images

```
docker images -a
```

Output -

```
REPOSITORY                TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
datahub/postgres          development         e7707e670ad4        35 minutes ago      265 MB
```

Remove that image  ( Use -f if required )

```
docker rmi IMAGE_ID_HERE
```

4) Restart your service again

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-filename.yml up --build postgres_service
```

This time you can see that your `docker-entrypoint.sh` and `dump.sql` will execute.

Answer (score -1):

The answers here somewhat solved the problem for me, but the final step to get the `docker-entrypoint-initdb/*.sql` scripts working was to ensure there were no syntax issues in the sql scripts themselves (I had issues because I changed SQL versions in my Dockerfile).

If any exist, everything in the `docker-entrypoint-initdb/*.sql` scripts seem to get rolled back.

To check if there are any syntax script issues (or other issues) you may find it useful to look at the docker logs:

```
$ docker ps -all
```

Note: the `-all` ensures it lists those images that may have failed to start up too.

Find the image you just created and look for the container id which should be a 12 character hash:

```
$ docker logs baf32ff7ec03
```

Remember you still need to follow the other answers here - which are to rm the previously built images and to delete your data folder (back it up if you need to).